# Format string text to a specific position

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, position, string-formatting

In a Windows Phone 8 project I have the following listbox with some data:

[image: a busy cat]

I want to list all dates lined up with the red line I drew. Basically I want it to print the date N spaces after the start, not after the temperature.

Right now I have this but I'm not understanding how the formatation with the `{}` works.

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
      listboxData.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,-12}{1,8}",values[i].value + unit, values[i].date));
}
```

Can you explain me how it works and a possible solution for my problem?

Comment: [PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft(v=vs.71).aspx) comes to mind

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a ListBox then I would suggest changing the ItemTemplate to match the formatting you want. It looks like you already have a collection of objects that contain the temp reading and time of the reading (your values collection). So set the ItemsSource property to be that collection. You can do this in code

```
listBox.ItemsSource = values;
```

Or you can do it in xaml

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding values}" />
```

The above assumes that you have a DataContext that has a values property that contains your temp readings.

The next step is to change the ItemTemplate to fit your formatting

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding values}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="55"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding value, StringFormat={}{0}°}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding date, StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm}}"
                           Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Your solution looks promising, however my temps and dates are appearing over each other :/

Comment: @sparcopt Looks like OP forgot to specify the column on each `TextBlock`. Just add `Grid.Column="0"` for first `TextBlock` and `Grid.Column="1"` for second one.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you've got the format string right but the problem is the true type font. Not all characters are the same width. Courier new would work (all characters the same pixel width, including spaces) but that might not be what you want either. Might have to use a two column affair.. Maybe a table even?

For example. I'll print 10 chars of i and then of A

iiiiiiiiii

AAAAAAAAAA

See the difference in width? Stack overflow is using a true type font to display my post..